# How can we transfer data from one open Excel file to another in real time?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, dde

We have below situation and want the data to be transferred live, Any Help Please.

- 2 Separate Users - Gautam & Milan - Logged in to Windows RDP Server
- 2 Separate PC -  PC1 & PC2
- 2 Separate Excel Workbooks - Book1 & Book2 - Both Workbook are opened
  by users and closed only at end of the working day

Book1 is getting live data feed using DDE from a Software as well as we want to show our current stock position of products (which will come from Book2)

We want to use Book2 to inject current stock position into the Book1 to display the live price form DDE of software as well as current stock position from Book2

As soon as we change the stock data in Book2 it should be displayed in Book1.

Both Books are stored in same shared folder in windows server.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This is not a service site, so there is an expectation you have attempted something to research or resolve this on your own before posting your question. The ***[help]*** can explain how the site works so you can improve your question(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula to import data from on workbook to another.

=[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!A1

This will import the data from shell 'A1' which belongs to Book1 on Sheet1.

*Make sure both the workbooks are in same folder

Comment: I know this is just semantics, but the formula doesn't actually "import" the data to the other sheet, it is a link to the data in the cell referenced.